# CURL ERROR: 28::Operation timed out after 0 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received In Authorise.Net payment In Open cart

Tags: authorize.net, opencart2.3

I am getting this error only in live mode. When i turn live mode to test , It is working fine . I also tried to change 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10); to curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 100);
But still not working .

Answer (score 0):

My solution is changing server settings. Added those lines in /etc/resolv.conf :

```
options timeout:1
options single-request
```

Detailed explanation: http://www.math.tamu.edu/~comech/tools/linux-slow-dns-lookup/